# Switching buffers between header/implementation in emacs in obj-c (obj-c++) mode

Tags: objective-c, emacs

How do I make emacs switch between buffers with header/implementation files in obj-c (c++) mode (that is, between foo.[mM]{1,2} and foo.[hH]{1,2})? Is it possible to assign standard Xcode keyboard shortcut (ctrl+cmd) for running such a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this link](http://roupam.github.io/#sec-7). He describes this function:

```
(defun objc-in-header-file ()
  (let* ((filename (buffer-file-name))
         (extension (car (last (split-string filename "\\.")))))
    (string= "h" extension)))

(defun objc-jump-to-extension (extension)
  (let* ((filename (buffer-file-name))
         (file-components (append (butlast (split-string filename
                                                         "\\."))
                                  (list extension))))
    (find-file (mapconcat 'identity file-components "."))))

;;; Assumes that Header and Source file are in same directory
(defun objc-jump-between-header-source ()
  (interactive)
  (if (objc-in-header-file)
      (objc-jump-to-extension "m")
    (objc-jump-to-extension "h")))

(defun objc-mode-customizations ()
  (define-key objc-mode-map (kbd "C-c t") 'objc-jump-between-header-source))

(add-hook 'objc-mode-hook 'objc-mode-customizations)
```

Comment: This was close - it does work as needed switching from .m to .h, but not vice-versa, since the .h is opened in c-mode, not objc-mode (and I get `C-c t is undefined`. Is there a way to provide regexp(s) that would tell emacs when an .h file should be opened in objc-mode?

Comment: Yes. There are several solutions. The easiest would be a comment like this at the top of the header (first line): `/* -*- mode: objc -*- */` You also can work with the `find-file-hook` and decide dynamically which mode should be chosen (for example [this solution](http://bretthutley.com/programming/emacs/opening-a-cobjective-cc-header-file-in-emacs/)), but I would stick with the header.

Comment: Right, header should definitely go to a 'new objc class file' template, however adding a `find-file-hook` works fine on existing files created without emacs magic header. However, is it possible to grep for Objective-C/C++ specific keywords in the header file itself to make a decision whether to use objc-mode, c++-mode or c-mode?

Comment: @kervich well, kind of. The [emacs wiki suggest a solution with the `magic-mode-alist`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ObjectiveCMode)

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has built-in support for jumping from header file to implementation file using ff-find-other-file:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda() 
  (local-set-key  (kbd "C-c m d") 'ff-find-other-file)))
```

CC mode includes C, C++, Java, Objective C, etc.

Comment: If I run this in Obj-C mode for MyFile.h it would ask me to find or create MyFile.c (not .m), which is not what I need. Perhaps I should first adjust my objc-mode?

Comment: Try `(require 'find-file) ;; for the "cc-other-file-alist" variable`
    `(nconc (cadr (assoc "\\.h\\'" cc-other-file-alist)) '(".m" ".mm"))`

Comment: Now it would only open implementation (.m) when the header file is in the active buffer (it was working ok for switching from .m to .h before messing with `cc-other-file-alist`

Comment: See this wiki page http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ObjectiveCMode, it gives several piece of code for dealing with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to extend the `eassist-switch-h-cpp` function from CEDET's contrib to work with ObjC files, in addition to C/C++ code. The change is simple, add following code to your init file:

```
(eval-after-load "eassist"
 '(progn
   (setq eassist-header-switches '(("h" . ("cpp" "cc" "c" "m"))
                ("hpp" . ("cpp" "cc"))
                ("cpp" . ("h" "hpp"))
                ("c" . ("h"))
                ("m" . ("h"))
                ("C" . ("H"))
                ("H" . ("C" "CPP" "CC"))
                ("cc" . ("h" "hpp"))))))
```

and you can call the `eassist-swith-h-cpp` function - it will handle switching between header and implementation files. And you may bound this function to selected key (`C-c t` in given hook):

```
(defun my/c-mode-cedet-hook ()
  (local-set-key "\C-ct" 'eassist-switch-h-cpp))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my/c-mode-cedet-hook)
```